# How to disable already selected date in jquery ui in second date input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

i am trying to get multiple date inputs. What i want to do is that when user selects first date then he should not be able to select the same date + the dates previous then selected date in the second text box. here is my code.i am new to this. Not good at jquery ui

```
<script>


$(function() {//alert("getPricing just got called");



$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',minDate: 0 });
//Date d1=new Date($("#datepicker").val());
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',minDate: 0});

});
$("#button").submit(function() {alert("getPricing just got called");
    var start   = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate');
    var days   = (end - start)/1000/60/60/24;
    alert(days);
});
</script>
```

now what i want is that user can not select the same date+previous dates (which is selected in `#datepicker`) at `#datepicker1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haridharan/KXqHc/19/),try this,

```
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, 
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          beforeShow: function() {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', $('#end_date').val());
           }
     });

    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
          beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, 
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          beforeShow: function() {
              $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#datepicker').val());
         }
     });
```